# Gitlab CI copy file to runner host

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My Gitlab CI generate some files from unittest resul and i need move this files to gilab runner host...

Theare are some way to copy files to my gitlab ci to another git runner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All files are processed and generated in the gitlab-runner host.

Gitlab runner copies your repo and works with it on the destination host.

[Job Artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html) generated are stored on gitlab and stored between executions. You can accces them from the gitlab-runner as another part of your repository.

For example:

```
artifact_download:
  stage: test
  script:
    - 'curl --location --output artifacts.zip --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/jobs/42/artifacts"'
```

[Here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#get-job-artifacts) are the docs that explain how to access them from the `yml`

Comment: :) you welcome @LucianoCastro !!! I'm proud to see it helped to you!!